# How i can find all points of circle?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

How do I find all points of a circle, given the radius and the coordinates of the center point?

Comment: what do you mean "of a circle"? The circumference? The points within the circle?

Comment: All infinitely many of them? Or just some of them?

Comment: A circle have an infinite number of points. Can you please clarify your question a bit?

Comment: You could easily find all of them with brute force + pythagorean theorem

Comment: you know the eq. of circle (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2 then find y by putting values of x by a loop and put the limits of x to h-r from h+r . Remember for each value of x you will get two values of y

Comment: How many do you need to draw a circle? So isn't that enough you provide those? :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equation of a circle is (x-h)^2 + (y -k)^2 = r^2.
Where:

```
x = x-coordinate
y = y-coordinate
h = x-coordinate of the center point
k = y-coordinate of the center point
r = radius
```

Because the distance from the center to a point on the circumference on the x-axis, the y-axis and the radius form a right angled triangle where the x-Distance is the base, y-distance is the height and r is the hypotenuse of that right angled triangle. For a circle with center (0,0) the equation of a circle is x^2 + y^2 = r^2 (which is the Pythagorean Theorem).

You could also use the identities cos theta = y/r => y = r*cos theta and sin theta = x/y => x = r*sin theta and iterate over theta from 0 to 360 degrees

So given a center point (h,k) and radius r you can find the points (x,y) that lie on the circumference of the circle.

Then you can have a function to check if a certain point lies in a within the circumference or not. What exactly do you need this for?